# How to migrate from Jenkins week Ubuntu package to LTS?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, ubuntu-14.04, apt, jenkins

I'm currently running the Jenkins weekly Ubuntu package from https://jenkins.io/download/ on Ubuntu 14.04. Specifically I'm on Jenkins 2.138 (the latest) from https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/.

I'd like to migrate from the weekly to the more stable LTS release line. I'd like to wait until a new LTS release that's newer than our current weekly version (2.138) comes out, upgrade to that, and then stay on the LTS release line.

**How can I orchestrate this migration without losing anything?**

I wasn't able to find a Jenkins weekly → LTS migration guide for people who have Jenkins installed from the jenkins.io Debian/Ubuntu packages (they all seem to refer to the `jenkins.war` version).

We currently have `deb http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian binary/` listed in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pkg_jenkins_ci_org_debian.list` (pkg.jenkins-ci.org seems to be a mirror of pkg.jenkins.io). Would it be enough to simply edit that file, changing it to `deb https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/` (that is: changing the weekly apt URL to the stable/LTS one), and then run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade jenkins`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plan of action: changing the repository, and then running `apt-get update` will work assuming: the name of the package, `jenkins` is the same in both repositories. It shouldn't be hard to check this.

Other than that: I would make the following recommend the following

1. Make sure you make a backup of your server before starting this.
2. If you have a test server you can run a practice migration first, I would highly recommend it.

Alternative: You can use `apt-mark hold jenkins` to hold the `jenkins` package at some point, and it won't upgrade unless you unhold it `apt-mark unhold jenkins`. This way to you hold yourself on a 'stable' release until you are ready to upgrade.

Comment: I finally got round to following this procedure and it seemed to work perfectly, thanks!